# SharePoint Online: What is the difference between standalone SharePoint Online Plan1 and SharePoint Online Plan2 in terms of Search

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

Can anbody explain in details the search features I would be missing if I choose the standalone SharePoint Plan 1 over SharePoint Plan 2?

I have looked at the comparison chart: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint/collaboration-tools-compare-sharepoint-plans-FX103789400.aspx

It says Enterprise search is not available, can somebody help me list the features which are classified as enterprise search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically just comparing SharePoint standard search vs. SharePoint enterprise search.  The blog post here highlights some of the differences between the two: http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

Detailed description of all services are available here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx

This also details regarding the search webpart availability, cross-site publishing and other search features along with all other features.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks. Can I ask a few specific questions (because several articles on the web have confused me). 1) Is it true that in Standad edition the search doesnt span across site collections? 2) Can I create custom search pages in the standard edition

Comment: You can create a "basic" search center and create custom search pages in it.  You can search across site collections with the search center.  You pretty much get everything but the content search web parts, some limitations on content processing, and no advanced query rules.

Comment: Thanks, that clears my confusion. Sorry, I edited your answer to add one more link. I will accept your answer as soon as my edits are approved.

Answer (score 0):

there is no big difference between Standalone Plan 1 vs Plan 2. I found only one difference.

**Search vertical: “Video”**

A targeted search experience that displays results that are custom filtered and formatted for video content.

For complete Search Comparison, please visit this link, this will explain all the search feature and comparison between plans, between standard vs enterprise, between O365 plan.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-search-service-description.aspx

Comment: There a few other differences as well. After some more searching I found that Search webparts are only available in Plan2, cross site publishing (it is based on search) is available only in plan2.[SharePoint Online Service Description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx) - complete comparision. But as stated in my comment for John's answer above, I am still confused over specific questions from reading various blogs on the web.

Comment: are you looking for Office 365 or On premises, because the MSFT technet mentioned only one feature missing from Plan1 vs plan 2. but you are talking about on premises things. go through the technet for official position.

Comment: the link in my earlier comment to you has the complete differences between SharePoint Online Plan1 & Plan2. It is definitely Office 365.